# How to read a HTTP cookie in Common Lisp?

Tags: http, cookies, lisp, cgi, common-lisp

I would like to make a single CGI program in Common Lisp, that reads a cookie.

It is clear to me that I can send a Cookie by sending HTTP headers. Yet, I would like to know how to read a cookie on a server, through CGI program, from the client who is accessing the program.

Comment: Why not simply use one of the web frameworks, e.g. Clack?

Comment: Clack is complex, why make it more complicated?

Comment: The user written part of the code will be less complex. And if you are setting up web-server <-> cgi program interaction, you might as well set up clack, I'd think. But I do not know your setup, so I might be guessing wrong here.

Comment: On a second thought, for this task Clack might be more complex from the user perspective. You do need to run a separate process for your web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CGI mechanism passes the cookie using the `HTTP_COOKIE` environment variable. ANSI Common Lisp doesn't have any API for accessing POSIX and Windows system environment variables. Implementation-specific functions, or else an implementation's FFI, is used to achieve the equivalent of C's `getenv`.

The [Common Lisp Cookbook](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/os.html#env) suggests this:

```
* (defun my-getenv (name &optional default)
    #+CMU
    (let ((x (assoc name ext:*environment-list*
                    :test #'string=)))
      (if x (cdr x) default))
    #-CMU
    (or
     #+Allegro (sys:getenv name)
     #+CLISP (ext:getenv name)
     #+ECL (si:getenv name)
     #+SBCL (sb-unix::posix-getenv name)
     #+LISPWORKS (lispworks:environment-variable name)
     default))
MY-GETENV
* (my-getenv "HOME")
"/home/edi"
* (my-getenv "HOM")
NIL
* (my-getenv "HOM" "huh?")
"huh?"
```

Before using, I'd slightly modify this to:

```
(or #+CMU (let ((x ...)) (if ...))
    #+Allegro ...
    #+CLISP
    ...
    default)
```

Comment: Looks like [Osicat](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/osicat/manual/osicat.html#Environment) has `(environment-variable name)` for posix systems, incl. windows. Nice to see the bare bones code though.

Comment: Also maybe worth refering to the newer, maintained and editable copy of the cl-cookbook ? https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/os.html

Comment: another reason would be this one: http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/os.html that they say this examples is outdated and lacks implementations. Now `uiop:getenv` comes with asdf.

Comment: @Ehvince have these implementations recently changed how they expose the getting of an environment variable?  I cannot see any difference between the two versions of `my-getenv`.

Comment: I doubt it :) I think he just added implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Kaz answer, we need to get an environment variable. But I won't refer to the cl-cookbook[1], now we have this solution that comes with asdf:

```
(uiop:getenv)
```

Also the [Osicat](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/osicat/manual/osicat.html#Environment) library (os, files and directories) has `(environment-variable name)` for posix systems, incl. windows.

[1] the cl-cookbook on sourceforge is old and sometimes outdated. There is a copy on github, maintained (well, a bit) and editable: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/os.html (https://github.com/LispCookbook/cl-cookbook/).

**edit**: the cookbook on github has been [edited accordingly](https://github.com/LispCookbook/cl-cookbook/pull/63#event-1086963213) and should be deployed soon on https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/os.html

Comment: Not to mention that there is probably somewhere a library for CGI programming in the first place where you just do `(get-cookie)` or whatever.

Comment: Note that the `my-getenv` I posted is also a (one function) library, like `uiop` and `Osicat`.  To get an environment variable, all three have to do the same thing at some level: call `lispworks:environment-variable` on Lispworks, `sys:getenv` on Allegro and so on.

Comment: you're right and it was really nice to see the low level. I like one-liners sometimes though :)